# How to get data from multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get data between 3 tables using Eloquent queries.

```
Table 1
  - user (hasMany relationship with orders)

Table 2
  - products (belogsToMany relationship with orders)

Table 3
  - orders (belongsToMany relationship with products)

Pivot table
  - order_details (Pivot table between products and orders)
```

I've tried eager loading the relationships.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Model 
{
      public function orders()
        {
           return $this->hasMany('Model\Orders');
        }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    public function orders()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Order', 'order_details', 'product_id', 'order_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Orders.php**

```
class Orders extends Model
{
      public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('Model\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Model\Product', 'order__details', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity', 'price')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Eager loading returns the entire dataset, i'm trying to retrieve for a particular user.

Comment: *Eager loading returns the entire dataset, i'm trying to retrieve for a particular user.* how did you actually retrieve the record if we may know?

Comment: I figured it out by doing this:   public function orders() {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $orders = User::with(['orders.products'])->where('id', $id)->paginate(4);
    return response()->json($orders);
  }

Comment: But now i get pagination issue..

Comment: the problem is? fyi that asking additional question in a question is no good.

Comment: Thanks Zain but i fixed it already.

Comment: What is `orders.products`? shouldn't it be `orders`

Comment: Orders has a relationship with products.

Comment: Ok. I got it. But what problem/error you are facing?

Comment: Now i'm facing a pagination error in my frontend, i should probably start a new question for this, thanks Zain.